# Python 3.5.0 - Break is outside loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code written:

```
Value = input("LOL")
LetterNum = 1

for Letter in Value :
    pass
print("Letter ",LetterNum,"is",Letter)
LetterNum += 1
break
```

I can't get it to display the numbers corresponding to the letters, all I'm getting is a `break outside loop`, what is causing that error?

Comment: Can you indent your code properly?  Python code blocks are defined by indentation level, so your `break` statement need to be indented one level (by appending 4 spaces) relative to the `for` block you want to `break` out of.

Comment: [code indentation matters in Python](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk)

Answer (score 3):

You need to spend some serous time at python tutorial sites or somehow get familiar with the language.

Your code won't work, not even close to what you want it to. I'm assuming this is what you want:

```
Value = "LOL"
LetterNum = 1

for Letter in Value :
    print("Letter ",LetterNum,"is",Letter)
    LetterNum += 1
```

Which will give you:

```
Letter  1 is L
Letter  2 is O
Letter  3 is L
```

1. Indentation, Indentation, Indentation, Indentation...
2. Understand how variable are assigned (very basic)
3. No need for `break` in that code if you already have a pre-set loop (start to end)
4. Indentation, Indentation, Indentation, Indentation...